# GitLab error fetching variables after restoring backup

Tags: gitlab

Yesterday, I have moved my GitLab installation to another machine.
It was installed with `docker-compose`, and I followed the official GitLab guide to back up and restore GitLab including the 'secrets' files.

Everything works so far, except the CI/CD variables in the admin area.

I get the error '`There was an error fetching the variables.`' when I navigate to this site.

Can you give me a hint in which log I can found more information about this error?

[image: Image of the error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I could solve the problem.

With the [Doctor Rake tasks](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/raketasks/doctor.html) I could determine where the problem was.
Afterwards I followed the steps to [reset the runner registration tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/raketasks/backup_restore.html#reset-runner-registration-tokens).
Finally I deleted al the instance variables in the dbconsole, by deleting them out of the database.

Answer (score 1):

Check first if this is similar to [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 218913](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/218913) which includes two possible root causes:

- Either you have an adblocker on, which could affect that functionality
- Or:

> go to the project settings `general -> Visibility, project features, permissions`
> In `Pipelines` (Build, test, and deploy your changes) select `Only Project Members`
>
> [image: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/uploads/0d745339883ee382417dae52f6b50f36/Screenshot_222.png]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But i did already try the suggested steps from this ticket. Unfortunately it didn't help me.

Comment: @MichaelBiehler Then I would suggest looking at https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/logs.html (right at the moment you are accessing this page, triggering the error message). And possibly opening a new ticket.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issus after restore a backup :

My solution was to delete variables from the database :

```
sudo gitlab-rails dbconsole --database main

gitlabhq_production=>delete from ci_instance_variables;
gitlabhq_production=>delete from ci_variables;
```

then it works